# How do I Import a csv file containing repeated lines of information (blocks) whereby for example a row beginning with 'T' refers to time etc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very long csv file with repeated blocks of information, however it's not perfectly regular:

```
T,2002,12,03,09,22,54
B,35,77,27,34,190,400,341,3447,940.3,303.5
G,3229987,41014,25,3447,1784033,21787,16,3447,940.3,303.5
R,3273751,46609,6452,3447,1810631,45933,6382,3447,940.3,303.5
D,NBXX,31,4.267,6.833,6.646,2.270,9.975,3.987
Y,194669,940.3,303.5,298.4,11.6,12.9,5.8,7,0000
T,2002,12,03,09,27,56
B,3520252,76702,297,3447,1906319,39865,305,3447,940.4,303.6
G,3231611,40449,13,3447,1785214,21650,25,3447,940.4,303.6
R,3273277,46425,6431,3447,1813279,45613,6425,3447,940.4,303.6
D,NBXX,28,-6.813,4.314,5.826,1.527,2.997,-9.648
Y,194767,940.4,303.6,298.4,11.4,12.9,5.8,9,0000
Z,2.782e-5,1.512e-5,1.195e-5,1.415e-5,8.290e-6,1.232e-5,2.319e-5
T,2002,12,03,09,32,59
.
.
.
```

the information isn't completely regular and some of the 'D' lines contain or less the normal number of elements e.g. most if not all 'D' lines contain 9 elements -

```
['D', 'ZBXX', '110', '2.590e-5', '1.393e-5', '1.032e-5e-6']
['D', 'ZBXX', '118', '2.641e-5', '1.402e-5', '1.027e-5', '1.237e-5', 
'6.553e-6', '9.466', '290.9', '6.1', '12.0', '6.2', '7', '0000']
['D', 'ZBXX', '110', '2.590e-5', '1.393e-5', '1.032e-5e-6']
['D', 'ZBXX', '118', '2.641e-5', '1.402e-5', '1.027e-5', '1.237e-5', 
'6.553e-6', '9.466', '290.9', '6.1', '12.0', '6.2', '7', '0000']
```

And I want it to look like:

```
Time [yy-mm-dd-hh-ss]     D[3]       D[4]   D[5]    D[6]    D[7]    D[8]    Y[4] Y[[5]  
2002-12-03-09-22-54     4.267       6.833   6.646   2.270   9.975   3.987   303.5   
2002-12-03-09-27-56     -6.813      4.314   5.826

2002-12-03-09-32-59
```

This is the code I have thus far:

```
year_i=np.array(1999) # Start year

dataframe_rows = []
for x in range(1,6): # we have 5 files
    # Create the name of file that will change within the loop
    year_str='nef'+str(year_i)
    start='C:\\Users\\'
    end=".dat"
    name_file=start+year_str+end # concat strings
    file_ = open(name_file, 'r+').readlines()

    rows = ""    
    for i in range(len(file_)):
        if (file_[i].startswith('Z')): #ignore lines starting with 'Z'
            continue
        string = file_[i]
        if (file_[i].startswith('B')): #ignore lines starting with 'B'
            continue
        string = file_[i]
        if (file_[i].startswith('G')): #ignore lines starting with 'G'
        continue
        string = file_[i]
        if (file_[i].startswith('R')):  #ignore lines starting with 'R'
        continue
        string = file_[i]
        if "T," in string:  
            if len(rows) > 0:
            dataframe_rows.append(rows[:-1])
            rows = ""
        string = file_[i].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        string = string[2:].replace(",","-")
        rows += string + ","

        #if "D," in string:
        # I want to select certain the last 6 elements and convert them into columns

        #if (file_[i].startswith('Y')):
        # I want to select the 3rd, 5th, 6th and last elements and convert them into columns

    else:
        string = file_[i].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        aux_row += string[2:] + ","

year_i+=1 # counter

fixed_rows = []
for row in (dataframe_rows):
    if (len(row.split(","))) == 18:
        fixed_rows.append(row)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(fixed_rows)))
```

Comment: so what's the question ? I suppose you wonder what would one do ?

Comment: yeah exactly, it's a dataframe management question I guess. How do you define columns based on the elements in repeated rows?

Comment: thanks for editing my question

Comment: I don't get it: do you know from the beginning that you want columns 'D[3]', 'D[4]', 'D[5]', 'D[6]', 'D[7]', 'D[8]', 'Y[4]', 'Y[5]' in your output ? Or do you want to choose the output columns depending on the content of the input file ?

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, there are very few lines in the csv files that break this regularity and I wanted them to be filled with NaN

Comment: My largest file has 1059724 lines - I tried the code on a faster computer and it worked eventually. Is it the size of the file or the code that is slowing it down?

Comment: see comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- You always want the 6 last values of D columns whatever the length + the 3rd, 5th, 6th and last values of Y columns whatever the length (note the first element is the letter itself so the ith value corresponds to the i+1th element)
- T, D and Y always exist

I would do something like that (here the input file is just considered like a text file, not particularly csv but the memory is reasonably used):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
finName = 'testInput.csv'
foutName = 'testOutput.csv'
colNames = ['date', 'D[-6]', 'D[-5]', 'D[-4]', 'D[-3]', 'D[-2]', 'D[-1]',
            'Y[4]', 'Y[6]', 'Y[7]', 'Y[-1]']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=colNames)
dictionary = {}
with open(finName,'rt') as fin:
    for i, line in enumerate(fin, 1):
        if line.startswith('T'):
            dictionary['date'] = datetime(*list(map(int,line.split(',')[1:7])))
        elif line.startswith('D'):
            shortLine=line.split(',')[-6:]
            for i in range(-6,0):
                colName = 'D['+str(i)+']'
                dictionary[colName] = float(shortLine[i])
        elif line.startswith('Y'):
            fullLine=line.split(',')
            for i in [4,6,7,-1]:
                colName = 'Y['+str(i)+']'
                dictionary[colName] = float(fullLine[i])
            df = df.append(dictionary,ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv(foutName)
```

---

If D lines do not always have more than 6 values (I think this is your last question), here is an alternative where columns 'D[-i]' are filled with values when they exist or 'nan' when they don't. In the imports at the beginning of the script, you should add `from numpy import nan`, then replace the block under `elif line.startswith('D'):` by:

```
fullLine=line.split(',')
for i in range(-6,0):
    colName = 'D['+str(i)+']'
    try:
        dictionary[colName] = float(fullLine[i])
    except:
        dictionary[colName] = nan
```

Comment: I'm coming with an alternative where D lines do not have always have 6 values.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked really well for my first file, but I used it for the other ones, which are similar, and it couldn't do it i.e. took ages to process and never came up with an error message

Comment: maybe your input is so huge, even the interesting values can not be kept in memory, like in this example... how many lines do you have in your input ?

Comment: about a million lines doesn't sound so huge to me... but I am not familiar with pandas and I don't how it behaves. Maybe the 'append' thing is not optimized and should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected output you require data from lines starting with "T", "D" and "Y"

Following lines can help (assuming that there are the same number of T,D and Y lines in input file)

```
import datetime

.....

file_ = open(name_file, 'r+').readlines()

values = [line.split(",") for line in file_]

T_data = [str(datetime.datetime(int(line[1]),int(line[2]),int(line[3]),int(line[4]),int(line[5]),int(line[6]))) for line in values if line[0]=="T"]
D_data = [[line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6],line[7],line[8]] for line in values if line[0]=="D"]
Y_data = [[line[3],line[4]] for line in values if line[0]=="Y"]

processed_data = [[T_data[i]]+D_data[i]+Y_data[i] for i in range(len(T_data))]

for line in processed_data:
    print(line)
```

**Update**

```
import datetime

.....

data = []
item = {}
with open(name_file, 'r+') as file:
    for textline in file: #
        line = textline.split(",")
        if line[0]=="T":
            if "T" in item.keys():
                if "D" not in item.keys():
                    item["D"] = ["Nan","Nan","Nan","Nan","Nan","Nan"] #
                if "Y" not in item.keys():
                    item["Y"] = ["Nan","Nan","Nan"]
                data.append(item) #It should append a dictionary object with "T", "D" and "Y" keys
                item = {}

                #data.append(item["T]+item["D"] + item["Y"])
            item["T"] = str(datetime.datetime(int(line[1]),int(line[2]),int(line[3]),int(line[4]),int(line[5]),int(line[6])))
        elif line[0]=="D":
            #item["D"] = [line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6],line[7],line[8]]
            #Use negative array index if you need last elements
            item["D"] = [line[-6], line[-5], line[-4], line[-3],line[-2],line[-1]] 
        elif line[0]=="Y":
            item["Y"] = [line[-6], line[-5], line[-3]]
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: However, if one of my 'D' lines is not of the same length, how do I add a condition such that only the empties (because it's an incomplete line) are NaN i.e. if line(len)==8

Comment: Handling that situations requires additional preprocessing of "D" lines. Can you provide example of that another "D" line?

Comment: It seems to me this solution put the whole input file into memory AND duplicate interesting values. In case the input is huge, as suggested by the question, this is not acceptable

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and help.

Comment: Some examples of 'D' which do not follow the pattern i.e. have 9 elements:  
['D', 'ZBXX', '110', '2.590e-5', '1.393e-5', '1.032e-5e-6\n']
['D', 'ZBXX', '118', '2.641e-5', '1.402e-5', '1.027e-5', '1.237e-5', '6.553e-6', '9.466', '290.9', '6.1', '12.0', '6.2', '7', '0000\n']
['D', 'ZBXX', '110', '2.590e-5', '1.393e-5', '1.032e-5e-6\n']
['D', 'ZBXX', '118', '2.641e-5', '1.402e-5', '1.027e-5', '1.237e-5', '6.553e-6', '9.466', '290.9', '6.1', '12.0', '6.2', '7', '0000\n']

Comment: How do you add the lines to a dictionary instead of just printing them - thank you